# Completing a C# Visual Studio Project by publishing

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, wix

I have coded a relatively simple project in C# on Visual Studio that I need to publish and make available to other devices (probably through a dropbox download link). The only thing it does is use windows forms and a ms-Access database.

Seeing as I have never published a program I have made before, I have a few questions that I can't seem to get answered:

> - What do I need to do to ensure the database works on someone Else's system (assuming they have access already installed)? I use connection
>     strings in my code but surely these are going to be different on
>     another device?
> - What is the simplest installer to use to build my solution? I have tried Wix but it seems a bit complicated for a first-timer like
>     myself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is put the DB in the project folder, and include it in the project. Then use the connection string like this:

```
Provider=..bla-bla-bla..;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.mdb
```

Then you can pack your EXE together with database in ZIP for example. User downloads, unpacks your app into a folder, and just starts it.. The "DataDirectory" defaults to your application's location for desktop apps.